# How do I download octet-stream as an xls file?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, file-upload, xls

I'm using VS2010, SQLExpress 2008 R2 & EntityFramework to build a document management program.

When submitting a form using `HttpPostedFileBase`, xls & doc formats are saved with "application/octet-stream" as it's content type. My problem is that when I download the file, it is not recognized as a xls or doc file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a few options:

1. Save the file format or extension in a database column as well (easiest).
2. Save your files to disk and keep the location(path) in the database (faster).
3. try a third party library that tries to read the binary file headers to determine its format (that almost never works).

Comment: Great, thanks. I thought that it was the content type that determined what format the file was going to be, but just adding the extension at the end made it work. =) Thanks!

Comment: your welcome, just be sure to add the correct extension for each file to avoid problems. If this answer helped mark it accordingly.